# How do I split an and_then chain into two parts?

Tags: rust, webassembly

I'm attempting to split [this future/and-then chain](https://rustwasm.github.io/wasm-bindgen/examples/fetch.html) in two, so part can be hidden in a crate, and the other exposed in an API.

Original, working code:

```
let future = wasm_bindgen_futures::JsFuture::from(request_promise)
    .and_then(|resp_value| {
        // `resp_value` is a `Response` object.
        assert!(resp_value.is_instance_of::<Response>());
        let resp: web_sys::Response = resp_value.dyn_into().unwrap();
        resp.json()
    })
    .and_then(|json_value: Promise| {
        // Convert this other `Promise` into a rust `Future`.
        wasm_bindgen_futures::JsFuture::from(json_value)
    })
    .and_then(|json| {
        // Use serde to parse the JSON into a struct.
        let branch_info: Branch = json.into_serde().unwrap();

        // Send the `Branch` struct back to JS as an `Object`.
        future::ok(JsValue::from_serde(&branch_info).unwrap())
    });

// Convert this Rust `Future` back into a JS `Promise`.
future_to_promise(future)
```

Attempted split, part 1:

```
pub fn fetch(...) -> impl Future<Item = JsValue>
// ...
 wasm_bindgen_futures::JsFuture::from(request_promise)
    .and_then(|resp_value| {
        // `resp_value` is a `Response` object.
        assert!(resp_value.is_instance_of::<web_sys::Response>());
        let resp: web_sys::Response = resp_value.dyn_into().unwrap();
        resp.json()
    })
    .and_then(|json_value: js_sys::Promise| {
        // Convert this other `Promise` into a rust `Future`.
        wasm_bindgen_futures::JsFuture::from(json_value)
    })
```

Part 2:

```
let r = fetch(...);

r.and_then(|json| {
    let branch_info: Branch = json.into_serde().unwrap();
    future::ok(JsValue::from_serde(&branch_info).unwrap())
});
```

This compiles, but results in the warning `` warning: unused `futures::future::and_then::AndThen` that must be used ``, and a runtime panic (In browser), which is presumably related. Per the original example I linked, this can be alleviated with the line `wasm_bindgen_futures::future_to_promise(r)` at the end, but when used after the split, vice intact function, we receive this error: `` expected associated type, found struct `wasm_bindgen::JsValue`. `` There is presumably a futures-specific way to resolve this that doesn't involve converting back to a JsValue and dealing with a promise at the end. I suspect this can be resolved with a short modification (Something like unwrap() at the end), but I've been unable to determine what, from the futures API docs.

Comment: Please review how to create a [MCVE] and then [edit] your question to include it. We cannot tell what crates, types, traits, fields, etc. are present in the code. Try to produce something that reproduces your error on the [Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org) or you can reproduce it in a brand new Cargo project. There are [Rust-specific MCVE tips](//stackoverflow.com/tags/rust/info) as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Part 2, you are chaining your future with `and_then` in the following:

```
r.and_then(|json| {
    let branch_info: Branch = json.into_serde().unwrap();
    future::ok(JsValue::from_serde(&branch_info).unwrap())
});
```

the problem is you are not assigning it to anything so you lost the result, You need to assign it to a variable and use it afterwards like following:

```
let r_fin = r.and_then(|json| {
    let branch_info: Branch = json.into_serde().unwrap();
    future::ok(JsValue::from_serde(&branch_info).unwrap())
});
```

After assigning it to `r_fin`, you can pass it to `future_to_promise`:

```
future_to_promise(r_fin)
```

This way you will use the chained future `r_fin`.

Comment: This answers my question, and prevents the ```warning: unused `futures::future::and_then::AndThen` that must be used```. I'm still experiencing the runtime panic, but this appears to be specific to wasm_bindgen, vice futures in general